# Управление state в react.js

Tags: javascript, babel, reactjs

Привет. Помогите плиз разобраться с состояниями. Нужно реализовать приложение с динамичным добавлением\удалением элементов. С REST получаем JSON, парсим в объект, на базе объекта строится селектор, при выборе добавляется элемент, описанный в объекте. Проблема: не получается реализовать удаление текущего элемента - всегда удаляется последний. Упростил пример:

```js
class Base extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      elements: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "Name"
      }]
    };
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  }
  add() {
    let newState = this.state.elements;
    console.log(newState[newState.length - 1]);
    newState.push({
      id: newState[newState.length - 1].id + 1,
      name: "Add manual"
    });
    this.setState({
      elements: newState
    })
  }
  remove(item) {
    let newState = this.state.elements;
    if (this.state.elements.indexOf(item)) {
      newState.splice(this.state.elements.indexOf(item), 1);
      this.setState({
        elements: newState
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    const elements = this.state.elements.map(
      (item, i) => < div key = {
        i
      } > < Select data = {
        item.id + " - " + item.name
      }
      /><button onClick={this.remove.bind(this, item)}>Remove</button > < /div>
    )
    return ( < div className = "Container" >
      <
      div className = "Row" >
      <
      div > Это содержимое Base <button
      onClick = {
        this.add
      } > Add item < /button> < /
      div > < div > {
        elements
      } < /div> </div > <
      /div>
    )
  }

}

class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.data = props.data;
  }

  render() {
    return ( <button>
      Это оригинал: {
        this.data
      } </button>
    )
  }
}
        
ReactDOM.render(
  <Base />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: А что показывает промежуточный вывод в консоль в методе remove() ? Может с индексом что не так? 
И if (this.state.elements.indexOf(item)) лучше заменить на (~this.state.elements.indexOf(item)) чтобы исключить ошибку с 0 индексом

Comment: До и после удаления массив модифицируется корректно: т.е. если я удаляю 2 элемент из 3-х, в массиве останется 1 и 3. Если после этого проверить state в Base - вернётся так же корректное значение. Проблема где-то на моменте вызова Select, с передачей параметров и обновлением стейта.
http://codepen.io/odmin/pen/yMbEGW

Comment: Конструктор в Select вызывается только при создании элемента. При ре-рендере он не вызывается и соотв. визуально остаются устаревшие данные. 

Если в методе render компонента Select заменить this.data на this.props.data, то все будет работать нормально. Использование this.props это более правильный подход к использованию компонентов

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё понял!

Answer (score 0):

Удаляйте элемент с помощью `delete arr[i]`. После, когда будете использовать массив, выполняйте проверку: `item !== undefined`. Все проблемы в индексах.